# How i can use if/else/elseif statment in my case - PHP

Tags: php

How i can use if/else/elseif... in my case,

Because when i try those statment,

It says: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

I need to repeat elseif more than 1x time

```
   $row = array();   
   $row[] = if($aRow['status'] == "deleted"){'code..'};
```

Comment: You cannot assign a conditional statement to an array element.

Comment: What is the expected results?

Comment: where does $aRow come from?

Comment: use this $aRow['status'] == "deleted" ? 'code..' : '';

Comment: @commanderZiltoid, $aRow is fetchAll(); from Database,

Comment: I will prefer you to write switch statement and handle all you cases there. see here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_switch.asp

Comment: @MubasharIqbal , and with "switch statement", shows error like with "if statement"

Comment: see Amir Zojaji solution. both cases will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are after. You would loop over each record in your result array you get from fetchAll(), put your if/elseif block here, then I'm assuming your doing some sort of processing and saving the value to $row array?

```
$row = array();

$result = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($result as $aRow){

    if($aRow['status'] == "deleted"){
        //do something
        $row[] = //whatever
    }
    elseif($aRow['status'] == "something else"){
        //do something else;
        $row[] = //whatever else
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to assign the result:

```
$row = array();   
$row[] = $aRow['status'] == "deleted" ? 'code..' : null;
```

When you need to do more things depending on `status`, best way would be to introduce a function for that:

```
function process($aRow) {
    if ($aRow['status'] == "deleted") {
        // do something when `deleted`
        return 1;
    } elseif ($aRow['status'] == "new") {
        // do something when `new`
        return 2;
    } elseif ($aRow['status'] == "updated") {
        // do something when `updated`
        return 3;
    } else {
        // do something else
        return 4;
    }
}

$row = array();
$row[] = process($aRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways for implementing this by PHP:

**The 1st way**

you can use if/else/elseif:

```
if ($status_var=="deleted")
  {
  //code .....
  }
elseif ($status_var=="inserted")
  {
  //code .....
  }
elseif ($status_var=="edited")
  {
  //code .....
  }
esle
  {
  //code .....
  }
```

**The 2nd way**

You can use switch/case structure:

```
switch ($status_var)
  {
  case "deleted":
    //code .....
    break;
  case "inserted":
    //code .....
    break;
  case "edited":
    //code .....
    break;
  default:
    //code .....
  }
```